Power Bi connection error (simba snowflake odbc driver error )
I am facing issue while i connect snowflake with power BI,
Till yesterday it's working fine, But now when i try to edit old query or add new query i got error.
"The 'Driver' property with value '{Simba Snowflake ODBC Driver}' doesn't correspond to an installed ODBC driver.
enter image description here
my all credential are correct and i also try to run that query in snowflake but it working fine.
so how can i solve this error?
i check version of the power BI, restart the laptop.
also check credentials and also check query.

It looks like the version in the Microsoft Store is currently broken. The version on the Power BI site works just fine, despite having the same version number as the store version.
You need to uninstall Power BI and then reinstall it with the file from the website (not the Microsoft store). You can download it here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58494
